# Ruby DateTime.Parse to local time

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have a date string `20101129220021`, so I will use

```
require 'date'
d = DateTime.parse('20101129220021')
```

This part works fine, and I get a date, which is in UTC.

My question is, how can I convert this into my local time? I tried many methods like extracting the time part using `d.to_time` and manipulate the result, but it didn't work. As far as I know, `DateTime` object is immutable. Can I please get some help?

Comment: What do you expect? The same time but with the timezone the same as your local time, or the above UTC time converted to your local zone?

Comment: Say you are in UTC +0300, do you want 2010-11-29 22:00:21 +0300 or 2010-11-30 01:00:21 +0300.

Comment: I want the later so that I can store in database directly without the need to convert again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a rational fraction based on the timezone to get the local time.

```
require 'date'

# Make this whatever your zone is. Using UTC +0300 here.
ZONE = 3

d = DateTime.parse('20101129220021') + Rational(ZONE,24)

d.to_s # => "2010-11-30T01:00:21+00:00"
```

Comment: This is for 1.8.X, if using 1.9+ then nash's answer is the way to go.

Comment: I have serious problem installing 1.9.2 on my OSX... I used rvm but still the version won't switch properly.

Answer (score 4):

```
irb(main):001:0> require "date"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> d = DateTime.parse('20101129220021')
=> #<DateTime: 2010-11-29T22:00:21+00:00 (70719276007/28800,0/1,2299161)>
irb(main):003:0> d.to_time
=> 2010-11-30 00:00:21 +0200
```

ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18)

Comment: I am on OSX, for lots of reason I didn't really upgrade to 1.9.2, therefore the above command doesn't work for me, sorry. My version is ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10]